# can Mainqueue do background task while using in NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

1)When we use mainQueue in NSURLConnection for sendasynchronousrequest ,How it gets response through running in background?because mainqueue is for updating UI only.For EX:

```
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue   mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
    [delegate receivedData:data];
else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
    [delegate emptyReply];
else if (error != nil && error.code == ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT)
    [delegate timedOut];
else if (error != nil)
    [delegate downloadError:error];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say mainQueue is for updating UI only is not strictly right.

The exact point is that mainQueue is used to update UI and so developers avoid to do any other tasks on the mainQueue to no introduce delays on the UI. It's not completely forbidden.

But, doing asynchronous task like a network request on the mainQueue is really a bad idea because it will introduce an unbounded delay that will completely break the smoothness of your UI

To not block your mainQueue you should execute your request this way :

- Create your own application operation queue

  ```
  NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
  ```
- then reuse your `operationQueue` anywhere you need it to execute your network requests

  ```
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:operationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
   if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
       [delegate receivedData:data];
   else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
       [delegate emptyReply];
   else if (error != nil && error.code == ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT)
       [delegate timedOut];
   else if (error != nil)
       [delegate downloadError:error]; }];
  ```

Another alternative, safer and more effective is to use [AFNetworking framework](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: If above method is in button IBAction Method, If i tap that button 3 time, that URLRequest will be in 3 time in Queue ?

Comment: @jeffWood yes, and the system will try to send them concurrently. If you want to send them sequentially you have to change the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property